# Which honorific is correct, oshumi or goshumi?

Tags: words, word-usage, honorifics

I want to ask a person about their hobbies. Go/O shumi ha nan desu ka? 趣味

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's ご趣味. As a general rule for nouns, ご beautifies a word which uses the on-yomi (e.g. ご質問 or ご主人), while お beautifies a word which uses the kun-yomi (e.g. お米 or お金).